# Why does this window.addEventListener fire first, before doc.ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener

In my test code below, I am confused why #5 fires so soon.

**This is script located in the SCRIPT tag in the HEAD section of my HTML Test Page.**

```
    window.onload=function(){
        console.log("1");
    };

    (function testFunc() {  // IIFE will fire right away
        console.log("2")
    })();


    </script>
    <SCRIPT src="jquery.js"></SCRIPT>
    <SCRIPT src="script.js"></SCRIPT>   


    <script type="text/javascript">

    $( document ).ready(function() { // jquery doc ready
        console.log("3");
    });


    window.addEventListener('load', function(){
        console.log("4")
    }, false);


    function testFunc5() {
        console.log("5")  // this is where 5 is defined
    };
    window.addEventListener('load', testFunc5(), false); // and here is where it is fired
```

**This is the code in my script.js file**

```
    $(function() {  // jquery document ready
        console.log("6");
    });

    $(function() {  // another jquery doc ready  
        console.log("7");
    });
```

I am not expecting 5 to be logged so soon.  I expected it to show up at the end.

**My console output is....
2, 5, 6, 7, 3, 1, 4**

The order of all the other numbers makes sense, but not 5.  It is added to the window.onload, and it's added after #4.  Yet it runs near the beginning.  The other window.onload and addEventListeners for load fire at the end.

Comment: Because you are calling function, not referring it `window.addEventListener('load', testFunc5, false);`

Comment: Thanks.  That did it.  It makes sense now.  I removed the () from testFunc5 and it works great.  5 now appears at the end of the output as expected.